# How to return escaped characters from MathLink?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I'd like to return Greek symbols through MathLink from a C function. However, returning the usual escape sequence (such as \[Alpha]) does not seem to work. Here's a minimal example .tm file (myalpha.tm) which creates a function that should simply return \[Alpha] :

```
void myAlpha P(( ));

:Begin:         
:Function:          myAlpha
:Pattern:           myAlpha[ ]
:Arguments:         { }
:ArgumentTypes:     { }
:ReturnType:        Manual
:End:

#include "mathlink.h"
void myAlpha() { MLPutSymbol( stdlink, "\\[Alpha]" ); }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { return MLMain(argc, argv); }
```

To compile it (on OSX) I use :

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mprep myalpha.tm -o myalphatm.c
/usr/bin/clang -c -I/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/CompilerAdditions myalphatm.c
/usr/bin/clang++ myalphatm.o -L/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -lMLi3 -lstdc++ -framework Foundation -o myalpha
```

And to run it I execute this little script :

```
link = Install["<fullpath>/myalpha"];
myAlpha[];
Print[%]
Uninstall[link]
```

Inside a Mathematica notebook this produces some binary symbol, and if I run it with MathKernel from the commandline then I get :

```
$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.
    Hold[Out[$Line - 1]]
```

My guess is that I haven't escaped everything correctly in the C string, but I'm not sure what the right escape sequence is. Since \ is the escape character in C I have escaped that, so the C-string reads "\\[Alpha]" and I've tried a variety of other options but to no avail.

Answer (score 10):

halirutan's answer is correct, but more could be said on the matter, so I'll expand.

First, MathLink/WSTP has no knowledge about the long-name form of various characters. The only Wolfram Language components that have the ability to parse and understand things like `\[Alpha]`, `\[LongEqual]`, etc., are the front end and the kernel.

To explain more from here, I'll need to dive into a bit about Unicode and character encodings.  A bit of background here.  Every long-name maps to a single Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).  Unicode code points have the [conventional notation of U+xxxxxx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_codepoint#Architecture_and_terminology), where the x's are hex digits and there might be 4, 5, or 6 of them (I'll consistently use 6 in this answer).

When the FE or kernel write or read files in ASCII (which they do by default, typically), there are a few different ways to write characters which aren't a part of ASCII so they'll be read.  Where long-names are available, the kernel and FE use long-names to try to make the files more human-readable when you're looking at them in a text editor.

But neither the FE nor the kernel uses long-names for internal representation of strings.  The internal representation uses some Unicode-friendly encoding variant.  There are four that get used, and each of them has an equivalent set of MathLink/WSTP functions corresponding to them.

- [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), a Unicode consortium standard using a variable number of 1-byte code units to represent a code point.
- [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), a Unicode consortium standard using a variable number of 2-byte code units to represent a code point.
- [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32), a Unicode consortium standard using a single 4-byte code unit to represent a code point.
- What we internally call "MathLink encoding", an encoding that uses the plain-text subset of ASCII characters to represent code points.

MathLink understands all four of those encodings, and automatically converts between them.  MathLink also supports a couple of encodings which cannot represent arbitrary code points (the `ByteString` and `UCS2String` variants, which I won't further belabor here).

halirutan's answer shows a correct example of using UTF-8.  I might add that, if you're using C++11 or later, there are some [string literal prefixes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) that can be quite helpful in speccing out string literals which are UTF-8/16/32. Annoyingly, MathLink rigorously requires prepending every UTF-16 and UTF-32 form with a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in order to function properly.  I'm not a big fan of this design decision, and it tends to make UTF-16/32 code clunky IMO, but that's the way it is.

MathLink encoding is what's used in the `String` variants (e.g., `MLPutString` or `WSPutString`).  MathLink encoding is basically ASCII with the following exceptions:

- `\\`: A literal backslash must be doubled.  As with other forms here, this is in addition to the doubling of literal backslashes in typical C strings, so in C, this actually looks like

```
const char* literalmathlinkbackslash = "\\\\"
```

- `\ooo`: A backslash followed by three octal digits is interpreted as the code point U+0000xx where xx is the hex equivalent of the octal number.
- `\.xx`: A backslash followed by a period and two hex digits is interpreted as the code point U+0000xx.
- `\:xxxx`: A backslash followed by a colon and four hex digits is interpreted as the code point U+00xxxx or, if between `D800` and `D8FF` inclusive, may be interpreted as a member of a [correctly matched surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_pair#U+D800_to_U+DFFF).
- `\|xxxxxx`: A backslash followed by a pipe and six hex digits is interpreted as the code point U+xxxxxx, if and only if the resulting hex number represents a valid Unicode code point.  This means the numbers between `00D800` and `00DFFF` inclusive, or greater than `10FFFF` are not allowed.
- A backslash followed by anything else is undefined behavior. A given bit of text following a backslash may or may not produce an error, but any behavior you observe should not be relied upon.

So, the UTF-8/16/32 and MathLink forms may all be used to communicate Unicode code points over MathLink. But long-names may absolutely not be used.  The attempt in the original question to use a single backslash is in MathLink's "undefined behavior" zone.  While the double backslash form now is sending a literal backslash, followed by a literal square bracket, etc.

Comment: John - do you know how I could write a WL function to automatically give back a string I could paste into my C++ code?  Something like `getString["\[Alpha]"]`, which would return `"\xce\xb1"` (or `"\u03B1"` or any of the other variants discussed in your answer)?  After reading these answers a few times I just need a function I can use blindly.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not an expert here, but one way to achieve what you want is to transfer [UTF8 codes](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768). I guess the assumption that you can simply transfer a string `"\[Alpha]"` as `Symbol` over MathLink and *Mathematica* interprets this for you, cannot be made. Therefore, the following is a different solution which works as expected (at least on my Linux here)

```
void myAlpha() { 
  MLPutUTF8Symbol( stdlink, "\u03B1", 2); 
}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This works on OSX as well but MLPutUTF8Symbol needs a pointer to an _unsigned_ char, so an explicit cast before the string is necessary. I.e. `MLPutUTF8Symbol( stdlink, (const unsigned char *) "\u03B1", 2);`.

Answer (score 2):

Another route to go would be to translate the symbol to the internal character codes used by *Mathematica*, retrieved via [`ToCharacterCode`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToCharacterCode.html):

```
In[5]:= ToCharacterCode["\[Alpha]"]

Out[5]= {945}
```

So in the C code you would use

```
MLPutFunction(link, "Symbol", 1);
MLPutFunction(link, "FromCharacterCode", 1);
MLPutInteger(link, 945);
```